# Convert min value integer to unsigned long

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion, integer, unsigned

I am trying to convert the min value of **integers** to an **unsigned long**, like the following:

`-2147483648 to 2147483648` the first value which is stored in the **integer** variable, and the second is the value that I'm trying to make my **unsigned long** variable takes.

So I know how to convert the min value of **integers** `-2147483648` to **unsigned int** as it appears in the main below :

```
int main()
{
    int d = -2147483648;
    unsigned int u = (d * -1);              

    printf("%u\n", u);                             //the output is "2147483648"
}
```

but when I'am trying to do the same with converting to **unsigned long** my output becomes the value of the max **unsigned long** value which is on my device `18446744071562067968`

```
int main()
{
    int d = -2147483648;
    unsigned long ul = (d * -1);              

    printf("%lu\n", ul);                             //the output is "18446744071562067968"
}
```

I searched a little bit about Data Types and their ranges, and I saw that the range of **unsigned long** is
`0 to 18446744073709551615`, and I figured that when we multiply the min value of **integers** with `-1` it doesn't change because the max value of **integers** is `2147483647`, so it stays `-2147483648`, and when I give it to the **unsigned long** which doesn't contain that value, it becomes the max value of its own range `18446744073709551615`.

So I tried to store the value of `-2147483648 * -1` in **long int** variable, which its range is

`-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807`, so it can store the value `2147483648`.

```
int main()
{
     int d = -2147483648;
     long int l = d;                 // l now contains -2147483648

     l *= -1;                        // now it becomes 2147483648

     unsigned long ul = l;           // now we managed to store 2147483648 in unsigned long variable

     printf("%ld\n", ul)             //the output is "2147483648"
}
```

And here my problem is solved, but I wanted to do it with casting this time like the following :

```
int main()
{
     int d = -2147483648;

     unsigned long ul = (long)(d * -1);          

     printf("%lu\n", ul)             //the output is "18446744071562067968" :(
}
```

But when I try to cast it in another way `unsigned long ul = -(long)(d);` the wanted output `2147483648` appears.

so my question is what the difference between the first casting and the second casting method and why it worked just with the second way?

Comment: Note: with `int d = -2147483648;  (d * -1);` is `int` overflow and _undefined behavior_ (UB).  The output seen is not specified by C.

Comment: Also note that on a platform with a 32 bit `int`, the type of  `-2147483648` will be a `long` or a `long long`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yeah, because there isn't "2147483648" in the integers range.

Comment: @Bathsheba yeah i am working in 64 bit platform.

Comment: Holy semicolon, what value do you expect `d * -1` to result in?  Do consider since it is UB, code could crash, return 0, return -2147483648 or ...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica as you said it will be `int` overflow and it will be the min value of integers "-2147483648"

Comment: "be int overflow and it will be the min value of integers" --> Not quite.  This is possible, but it is UB - anything may happen.  Good code does not rely on " it will be the min value of integers".

Comment: IMO, if code used hexadecimal constants and `x` rather than `u`, many answers  here would be apparent.

Comment: Yeah, you are right so I mustn't multiply the min value with -1 because it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @JaMiT I am just coding a program that takes signed integers and pass them to a function that in it's parameters is an unsigned long and i don't want to change it's parameters because I want to make that function to treat both signed integers and unsigned integers.

Comment: "_the min value of integers -2147483648_" - no, the min value of 32 bit signed integers is not set in stone. The current standard supports -2147483647 as the min value too.

Comment: Why don't you just do `u = d;`

Comment: Your claim "the max unsigned long value which is on my device 18446744071562067968" is false, you give the correct value later. That value is the result of `18446744073709551615 - 2147483648 + 1`  (which is how signed->unsigned conversion is defined)

Comment: @M.M yeah right my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You case is an undefined behaviour because `d * -1` is **2147483648** that cause overflow for an int.

To avoid this you need to cast before the operation the int value to a long or unsigned long value (as you have alredy done in the other example).

This because if the operation is done between 2 int, it was solved in int variable and cause overflow, after that in the assignement procedure it will be casted to unsigned long.

You need to prevent this with an early cast.

Comment: You could also use a long constant -- `d * -1L` would have the same effect without an explicit cast.

Comment: Yes is an alternative

Comment: yeah you are right, so when this operation (d * -1) calculated, it will result an undefined behavior, and it'll stay -2147483648 then it'll be casted to long with the min value of int, and then it'll be stored in unsigned long that will cause another overflow for unsigned long because it hasn't that value.

Comment: so as you said I need to do the early cast like this `(long)d` then multiply it with `-1` to prevent the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

So as razor said in the previous answer, I need to do an early cast to the **integer** `d`, and then multiply it with `-1`, as you can see in this way :

`unsigned long ul = -(long)(d);` or this way `unsigned long ul = ((long)d) * -1;`
they are both valid and it`ll not result any undefined behavior.

but in this casting way `unsigned long ul = (long)(d * -1);` the result is undefined behavior, why? let's explain it step by step.

we have `(d * -1)` and both of them are **integers**, so when I multiply `-2147483648` by `-1` the wanted expected output is `2147483648`, but unfortunately **integers** doesn't have such a value in it's range, and it'll result an undefined behavior, mostly the value will not change and it'll stay `-2147483648` even after multiplying it with `-1`.

then we cast the unchanged value, which is `-2147483648` to **long integer** and it'll hold it because it has it in it's range, so the value now still `-2147483648`, after it we store this value in an **unsigned long integer** and here it'll be an undefined behavior, because we are putting a negative number in **unsigned** value.

so to avoid this problem all what shall we do is to cast `-2147483648` to **long** then multiply it with `-1` ==> `((long)d) * -1`, because **long** can store the positive value `2147483648` due it's range.

and then we can store it in the **unsigned long int** without facing any undefined behavior.

here is a site for more details about data types range :

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm

Comment: tutorialspoint.com is not a reliable reference for understanding the nuances of C. _"it'll be an undefined behavior, because we are putting a negative number in **unsigned value**"_ is incorrect: [C has well-defined behavior for converting `signed` values to `unsigned`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3). Also note that the C standard allows `int` and `long` to be the same size (e.g., [on 32 bit Windows platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types)), which means that the cast to `long` is not portable.